# Does Installing KDE Plasma on Debian Bullseye Necessarily Install a Bunch of KDE Apps I don't Need?

Tags: linux, debian, gui, kde-plasma-5

Can I install just the KDE Plasma GUI/desktop interface on Debian 11 (Bullseye) without installing any KDE apps by default?
In other words, does doing `sudo apt -y install task-kde-desktop` install only the GUI and nothing else? Of course I don't mind getting the file manger and other such essential utilities, but I don't want anything from office software suites and drawing programs to web browsers to be installed without my consent.

Thank you! Oh, and please consider the fact that I am a Linux newbie (no more than a few days experience), but I'm OK with computers in general.

Comment: Run the command with `--dry-run` instead of `-y` and find out.

Comment: Alternatively you can [simulate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/404839/483098) installing as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the `kde-plasma-desktop` instead of `task-kde-desktop` through `apt` or `tasksel`, as said in the package [description](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/kde-plasma-desktop):

> KDE Plasma Desktop and minimal set of applications

> KDE is the powerful, integrated, and easy-to-use Free Software desktop platform and suite of applications.

> This metapackage pulls in the core modules released with the KDE Software Compilation including the basic KDE Plasma Desktop, minimal set of basic applications (browser, file manager, text editor, system settings, panel, etc.), important libraries and data.

command:

```
sudo apt install kde-plasma-desktop plasma-nm
```

Comment: This is the right answer. To anyone reading this, don't forget the `plasma-nm` part. It's the Plasma network manager. If you don't install it right away, connecting to the internet will be a pain in the but for newbies.

Note that, even thought it comes with a whole lot less bloat than the whole KDE suite, it is still very bloated (e.g. I had to go on and uninstall things such as KDE connect, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that [task-kde-desktop](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/tasks/task-kde-desktop) has kde-standard as a dependency, which in turn depends on all sorts of things you don't want, such as media player. What you want is [plasma-desktop](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/plasma-desktop) and probably [plasma-workspace](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/plasma-workspace) as well. Note that - for better or worse - this will not come with any of the integrated applications you'd normally expect, like file manager, so you'll have to install those separately.

Comment: [kde-plasma-desktop](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/kde-plasma-desktop) seems to be what pulls in the core apps like a file manager and terminal emulator, which one might expect for basic usage without adding too much bloat like the mentioned media player.